# How to hide certain categories in WP backend

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to hide in Wordpress admin backend certain categories posts from showing up in posts list (wp-admin/edit.php) for every user including admin. Categories ID`s are 49, 50, 51. Help me please :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you already try [Restrict Categories](https://wordpress.org/plugins/restrict-categories/) plugin to solve your problem ?

This plugin allows you to select which categories users can view, add, and edit in the Posts edit screen.

It is possible to restrict access based on the user role AND username.